# Spy on Jquery addClass function not working

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm trying to test whether the Jquery addClass fnuction has been called:

```
var data = "<form>Login Methods:<ul><li>SMS</li><li>Voice</li></ul></form>";

function injectOption() {
    console.log('in injectOption');
    data = $(data).addClass('some-class')[0].outerHTML;

    console.log('data is now');
    console.log(data);
}

describe("Our data array", function() {
    beforeEach(function () {

    });

    it('jquery.addClass called', function () {
        injectOption();
        spyOn($.fn, 'addClass');
        expect($.fn.addClass).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Check out the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2o8mokxm/4/). Somehow though, it always fails even though i can see in the console logs that the class was added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had couple of problems with your code. Main problem being you must initialize the spy before calling `injectOption()`.

```
it('jquery.addClass called', function () {
    spyOn($.fn, 'addClass');
    injectOption();
    expect($.fn.addClass).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuupola/2o8mokxm/5/).